# PHP and MySQL (Shorten the Query of Nested Loop)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask your help to shorten my query so that there will no be query in a while loop.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['cat']))
{

    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT category, extIdentifierID, identifier, ext_no FROM `push`.`transferlog_extcategory` LEFT JOIN `push`.`transferlog_extidentifier`  ON transferlog_extcategory.catID = transferlog_extidentifier.catID WHERE transferlog_extcategory.catID = :catID");
    $stmt->execute(':catID'=>$_POST['cat']);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
         echo '<tr><th colspan=2 style=background-color:#f5f5f5;>'.$row['identifier'].'</th></tr>';
         $sql = "SELECT extID extIDMain, extension, transfertype, ext_no, (SELECT COUNT(logID) FROM push.transferlog_agentlog WHERE extID=extIDMain ) logCount FROM push.transferlog_extension WHERE transferlog_extension.extIdentifierID = :extIdentifierID";
         $stmt2 = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute(':extIdentifierID'=>$row['extIdentifierID']);
         while($row1 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         { 
             echo '<tr><td>'.$row1['extension'].'</td> <td>'.$row1['logCount'].'</td></tr>'; 
         }
    }
    $dbConn = null;
}
?>
```

Sample Output
**Header1**
OutPut1
OutPut2
OutPut3
OutPut4
OutPut5
**Header2**
OutPut1
OutPut2
OutPut3
OutPut4
OutPut5
**Header3**
OutPut1
OutPut2
OutPut3
OutPut4
OutPut5

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: General tip: if you're running a nested query that depends on a value fetched from an outer/parent query, then you can pretty much almost ALWAYS rewrite both queries as a single joined query: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: You are also vulnerable [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so you'd better fix that up before you try optimizing anything.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, good luck with that. :)

Comment: As Marc said, this can usually be done with additional joins. Could you show table structures? Because more tables will be added to your query, it's important to know where to find the `category`, `extIdentifierID`, `identifier`, and `ext_no` columns, and your first query doesn't specify which table(s) they come from.

Comment: Also take the suggestions from Jason and Marc *very* seriously. I've seen frantic posts from developers whose sites were hijacked because they used the `mysql_*` library. Having a site hijacked can end your career. If you're independently wealthy you can ignore their advice.

Comment: @user2182381 Everything in your code is wrong. You should read into database queries with php. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. But can you gave me and advice to shorten my query?

Comment: Hi Ed Gibbs this programs was called by jquery ajax that base in Select input value. I just want know how to make a Query with that output

Comment: @Jason McCreary I'm still using the mysql_* because this is the syntax that are using for this program. I'll use PDO in my next project.